# Double sided inequality

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

[image: Screen shot from a text book]

Is it possible to type an inequality operator like in the image above to be used in Stack Exchange Mathematics domain. It would be nice if I could add those H<sub>1</sub> and H<sub>0</sub> labels too.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\gtrless` from `amssymb`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
  $\Omega(R) \underset{{H_0}}{\overset{H_{1}}{\gtrless}} \eta$

  $\Omega(R) \underset{{H_0}}{\overset{H_{1}}{\lessgtr}} \eta$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, Read that as `\Lambda` instead of `\Omega`. :-)